# Average of numbers from a text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class averagenames 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException , IOException 
   {
       double Average;
      FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\siva pavan\\Desktop\\studentavg.txt"); 
       
      BufferedReader Rd = new BufferedReader(file);
      Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
      
      String st= Rd.readLine();
      
      int sum=0;
      int count=0;
      while((st= Rd.readLine())!= null)
      {
          StringTokenizer stn =new StringTokenizer(st);
          System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
          String name=stn.nextToken();
          String rn=stn.nextToken();
          
          int English=Integer.parseInt(stn.nextToken());
          int Maths=Integer.parseInt(stn.nextToken());
          int Science=Integer.parseInt(stn.nextToken());
          int History=Integer.parseInt(stn.nextToken());
          
          Average=(English+Maths+Science+History)/4;
          count++;
          
          System.out.println("RollNumber: "+rn);
          System.out.println("Student: "+name);
          System.out.println("He has scored an average of : "+Average);
          System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
      }
      }  
}
```

I have written this program such that it provides me the average of the respective students marks and once I compile it I get:

```
RollNumber: Tom
Student: 2
He has scored an average of : 38.0
-----------------------------------------------------------
RollNumber: Harper
Student: 3
He has scored an average of : 36.0
-----------------------------------------------------------
RollNumber: Brown
Student: 4
He has scored an average of : 50.0
-----------------------------------------------------------
RollNumber: Smith
Student: 5
He has scored an average of : 50.0`enter code here`
```

**text file is**

List item

```
RollNum    Name   Science  Maths  English  History
1          ron     10       20     30       40
2          Tom      10       25     50       70
3          Harper   15       40     30       60
4          Brown    40       40     60       60
5          Smith    30       40     70       60
```

**I need the output to ask me the name of student and then print the average of specific student.**

What can I add in order that it asks me the student name to print the average?

Answer (score 0):

The flow of your program should be like

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
String wantedName = input.nextLine ();

while((st= Rd.readLine())!= null) {

    String name=stn.nextToken();
    if (name.equals (wantedName) {
        // process
    }

}
```

**edit**

Also be careful of Integer division in

```
Average=(English+Maths+Science+History)/4;
```

change to

```
Average=(English+Maths+Science+History)/4.0;
```

Comment: I did perform accordingly but still not able to solve this